# how to have a event listener to office 365 when a new mail is received

Tags: c#, .net, email, event-handling, exchangewebservices

I have migrated the mailbox from exchange server to office 365.

I have already written the code to connect to office 365 using the credentials and so i am able to read all the email that are there in the inbox.Please find the below code

```
 public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task test()
        {
            var pcaOptions = new PublicClientApplicationOptions
            {
                ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appId"],
                TenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantId"],
            };

            var pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                .CreateWithApplicationOptions(pcaOptions).Build();

            var ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All" };

            try
            {
                string password = "test";
                SecureString sec_pass = new SecureString();
                Array.ForEach(password.ToArray(), sec_pass.AppendChar);
                sec_pass.MakeReadOnly();
                // Make the interactive token request
                var authResult = await pca.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(ewsScopes, "test@demotenant.com", sec_pass).ExecuteAsync();
                //var authResult = await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync();
                // Configure the ExchangeService with the access token
                var ewsClient = new ExchangeService();
                //ewsClient.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "test@demotenant.onmicrosoft.com");
                ewsClient.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
                ewsClient.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken);

                FindItemsResults<Item> result = ewsClient.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(10));
                foreach (Item item in result)
                {
                    EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(ewsClient, item.Id);
                    String body = message.ConversationTopic;
                    String from = message.From.Address.ToString();

                }
                // Make an EWS call
                var folders = ewsClient.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot, new FolderView(10));
                foreach (var folder in folders)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Folder: {folder.DisplayName}");
                }
            }
            catch (MsalException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error acquiring access token: {ex.ToString()}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.ToString()}");
            }
        }
```

Now i am looking to add a listener which can run this code whenever a new mail is received in the inbox.
Can someone suggest me on how i can do this.

Answer (score 0):

EWS Streaming or push notifications would be one way to do this in EWS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/notification-subscriptions-mailbox-events-and-ews-in-exchange. A better approach would be to use Webooks in the Graph API and don't use EWS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0 (unless you need you code to run OnPrem). The other thing I would suggest is look at Power Automate (previously Flow) which also has the ability to trigger a large number actions on new Mail receipt.